# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str", when I try to extract values from request response

Tags: python, python-requests, typeerror

I am getting the following error: `"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"` and it's happening when I try to do the following:

```
response = requests.get('https://randomuser.me/api?results=1&gender=&password=upper,lower,12&exc=register,picture,id&nat=US', headers=headers).json()
results = response['results']
firstname = results['name']['first']
lastname = results['name']['last']
streetname = results['location']['street']['name']
streetnumber = results['location']['street']['number']
city = results['location']['city']
state = results['location']['state']
zipcode = results['location']['postcode']
phone = results['phone']
print(firstname, lastname, streetname, streetnumber, city, state, zipcode, phone)
```

The response of the request is the following:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "gender": "male",
        "name": {
            "title": "Mr",
            "first": "Vilho",
            "last": "Nevala"
        },
        "location": {
            "street": {
                "number": 5260,
                "name": "Satakennankatu"
            },
            "city": "Ypäjä",
            "state": "Päijät-Häme",
            "country": "Finland",
            "postcode": 90828,
            "coordinates": {
                "latitude": "63.8355",
                "longitude": "-80.4611"
            },
            "timezone": {
                "offset": "-10:00",
                "description": "Hawaii"
            }
        },
        "email": "vilho.nevala@example.com",
        "login": {
            "uuid": "f918cf9e-edd0-4723-aca9-a7b835933d64",
            "username": "happyfish285",
            "password": "hfjZmaLSgLLs",
            "salt": "411bCjmy",
            "md5": "1ce0803440b62127f514fcf1481bff03",
            "sha1": "48a8ca9e4ad776b996cba0748242d2f764d4de19",
            "sha256": "8f450337df8bb4a51edfbce0aa79c76afdc8f550c2ace3710175ecee59b6a27b"
        },
        "dob": {
            "date": "1974-04-04T22:25:46.000Z",
            "age": 48
        },
        "registered": {
            "date": "2021-08-14T08:42:14.407Z",
            "age": 1
        },
        "phone": "04-289-786",
        "cell": "042-381-81-43",
        "nat": "FI"
    }],
    "info": {
        "seed": "38da251006442a4a",
        "results": 1,
        "page": 1,
        "version": "1.4"
    }
}
```

The request response isn't empty. It's completely fine, this is the only error I get.

Full Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\documents\main\main.py", line 100, in <module>
    GetInfo()
  File "c:\Users\user\documents\main\main.py", line 36, in InfoGen
    firstname = results['name']['first']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: the problem is that `results = response['results']` is a list object so you have to access the elements by index (which you don't do) before accessing the other elements. So you should do `results = response['results'][0]` instead

Answer (score 0):

`results = response['results']`

Here `results` is a list of dictionaries.

Use `results = results[0]` to get the first dictionary.

Now

```py
firstname = results['name']['first']
lastname = results['name']['last']
...
...
```

will work.